# How does Deno resolve Rust plugins when deployed

Tags: rust, deno

I'm having trouble understanding the deployment model for creating Deno + Rust plugins. My application has a need for certain performance elements which are in Rust and a plugin is perfect. I've read articles such as https://alexandrempsantos.com/deno/creating-a-deno-plugin/ which explains developing the plugin.

What is completely unclear to me is if Deno uses ESM to resolve dependencies, what happens when you add a Rust dependency? I can see where it happens ie `Deno.openPlugin('./rust-plugin/lib.rs');` seems to do.

Adding in the flags on the CLI `-unstable --allow-plugin` is also necessary.

The confusing part is how it resolves that dependency when deployed or run. Does Deno consume the raw .rs file and compile on the fly at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the manual page [Foreign Function Interface (FFI) API](https://deno.land/manual@v1.17.3/runtime/ffi_api), you can't load a Rust source file. Rather, you compile the source file to a library file first (`.dll`/`.dylib`/`.so`), then load the library file.

Additionally, the `--allow-plugin` argument is legacy, now replaced by `--allow-ffi` (e.g. `deno run --allow-ffi --unstable module.ts`)

*Rather than copy the contents of the manual page, here please see the multiple examples in the manual.*